# Is there a better way to select this elements in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu, with some submenu items, and I would like when I select some submenu item, change the main label of the system. For example, for item 1 of menu 1 would change label to 'System A', for item 1 of menu 2 would change label to 'System B'.

Here´s the code, but doesn´t work well..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#choiceA ul li ul li a').click(function() {
    // change label to System A
    $('#labelSystem').html('System A');
  });

  $('#choiceB ul li ul li a').click(function() {
    // change label to System B
    $('#labelSystem').html('System B');
  });

});
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="htitulo">System  - <div id="labelSystem"></div></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="choiceA"><a href="#">Menu1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="choiceB"><a href="#">Menu2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a id="option1" href="">Submenu 1-1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="option2" href="">Submenu 1-2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a id="option3" href="">Submenu 2-1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="option4" href="">Submenu 2-2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="option5" href="">Submenu 2-3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here´s the fiddle for that...

https://jsfiddle.net/L2xd9jeu/

Comment: I will reformulate the question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, do you have an answer for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Working with the example given by OP, here is what I would do :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#choiceA li:first-child a').click(function() {
        // change label to System A
        $('#labelSystem').text('System A');        
    });
    $('#choiceB li:first-child a').click(function() {
        // change label to System B
        $('#labelSystem').text('System B');
    });
});
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2xd9jeu/1/).